# Regular Expression spaces and words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm pretty new with regular expressions. I'm trying to write a regular expression for a space followed by the word "IN" followed by another space.

So basically " IN ". I will eventually do a case insensitive split with it.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(*REG EX*, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] parts = regex.Split(strValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"\s+IN\s+"
```

Make sure to ignore case.

Comment: `+` aren't needed in this case

Comment: I believe they are @ExDev, as there may be more than one space. You need to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `*REG EX*` should be `" IN "`.
(Seriously, its  `" IN "`)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(" IN ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

> In case, if you have other whitespace characters i.e., other than space(), you can always use Juan's solution(`"\s+IN\s+"`). Here, [`\s`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) means [any whitespace character](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{1}IN\s{1}");
        string[] split = regex.Split(input);
```